# Cropping a long sized image

Tags: php

OK, let's say I have this image:

[image]

In my Java game, I use a cropping method which crops each monster of 32x32 pixels and thus puts in `monster[0]` onwards. Anyways, in PHP, is there some way I can do this? Like crop an image and go from there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're outputting to a web browser, you should just use [CSS sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/). Your image is conveniently already in the correct format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `imagecreatefromgif()` with PHP where you can create a new image on the fly by giving specific x and y positions. Rather than just me copy/pasting the code, here is the link to the documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

You can also use different variations of `imagecreatefromgif()` such as `imagecreatefromjpeg()` or `imagecreatefrompng()` etc

All are linked to on the PHP documentation page as well as more examples in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! You can see I did this and added a bit more 'flair' :P http://mystikrpg.com/mapcrop.php

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can crop the image via imagecopyresampled the man page 
http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopyresampled.php
You just have to set the correct offset.

if this should be displayed in a Browser you can do it even via CSS

```
.selector {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(theimage.gif) -32px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This one works.. sort of... but there's a grey border around the image of `.selector`... Hmmm

Comment: try this: 
    background: transparent url(theimage.gif) -32px 0px no-repeat;
    border: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Don't crop it. You can use it as it is with [CSS background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp). The the sive of a  and move the background to the image you want. It is faster than loading every image on its own.